# Simple ListView: when I Search it goes the previous position, not to the searched one

Tags: android, listview, search

In my second Activity I put a ListView.
By clicking any item it brings you to to several Activities.
I added a search option on top of it, because it's a huge one.
When I search to get an item, it goes to the previous original position.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    EditText edtsearch;
    //SearchView sv;
    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> pcs;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Lvid);
        edtsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bbb);




         final String pcs [] = {"BARURA\n(EB-0851) COMILLA","DAUDKANDI\n(EB-0079) COMILLA","COMPANIGONJ\n(EB-0087) COMILLA","GOURIPUR BAZAR \n(EB-0088) COMILLA","RAMCHANDRAPUR\n(EB-0112) COMILLA","CHANDINA SAMABAY\n(EB-0131) COMILLA","DHARMAPUR\n(EB-0200) COMILLA","SASHANGACHA\n(EB-0316) COMILLA","BATAKANDI\n(EB-0420) COMILLA","DEBIDWAR\n(EB-0853) COMILLA","CHOUDDAGRAM\n(EB-0859) COMILLA","HOMNA\n(EB-0891) COMILLA","COMILLA CO-OPERATIVE\n(JS-0026),COMILLA","LAKSHAM\n(JS-0117),COMILLA","BURICHANG\n(JS-0185),COMILLA","GUNABATI\n(JS-0260),COMILLA","RAMKRISNAPUR\n(JS-0308),COMILLA","JAFARGONJ\n(JS-0365),COMILLA","NALGHAR BAZAR\n(JS-0438),COMILLA","GANDAMATI BAZAR\n(JS-0479),COMILLA","PAYERKHOLA\n(JS-0507),COMILLA","AK FAZLUL HOQ ROAD CORP.\n(JS-0515),COMILLA","MOHANPUR BAZAR\n(JS-0560),COMILLA","SHASHIDAL BAZAR\n(JS-0594),COMILLA","FAKIRBAZAR\n(JS-0595),COMILLA","NANGOLKOT\n(JS-0601),COMILLA","BULAIN BAZAR\n(JS-0603),COMILLA","ALKARA\n(JS-0608),COMILLA","CHAWK BAZAR\n(JS-0634),COMILLA","SUNDALPUR\n(JS-0638),COMILLA","KAMALLA\n(JS-0643),COMILLA","BAIRA\n(JS-0687),COMILLA","DULALPUR BAZAR\n(JS-0696),COMILLA","BHOWKSHER BAZAR\n(JS-0721),COMILLA","KANDIR PARH\n(JS-0731),COMILLA","SHAHEBABAD BAZAR\n(JB-0836),COMILLA","COMILLA CADET COLLEGE\n(JB-0839),COMILLA","COMILLA EPZ\n(JB-0909),COMILLA","BHARASHAR BAZAR\n(JB-0941),COMILLA","COMILLA UNIVERSITY\n(JB-0945),COMILLA","ALAHABAD BAZAR\n(JB-0966),COMILLA","SUAGONJ BAZAR\n(JB-0968),COMILLA"};
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layout, R.id.txtid, pcs);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
 edtsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                Main2Activity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }


        });
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                 String text= lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CLICKED ON " + pcs[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent firstIntent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,
                                Barura.class);
                        startActivity(firstIntent);
                        break;

                        case 1:
                            Intent secondIntent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,
                                    Daukandi.class);
                            startActivity(secondIntent);
                            break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent thirdIntent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,
                                COMPANIGONJ.class);
                        startActivity(thirdIntent);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Intent fourthIntent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,
                                GOURIPUR.class);
                        startActivity(fourthIntent);
                        break;


                }
            }
        });

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't want a switch at all.

You could test the value of the string that is in the listview's position instead of the position itself.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

    final String text= lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CLICKED ON " + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Class clz = null;

    if (text.startsWith("BARURA")) {
        clz = Barura.class;
    } // else if () ... 

    if (clz != null) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, clz);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Note that having much over 20 activity classes means that you should re-structure something (personal opinion)

Comment: I am speechless. Thank u so much. God Bless you dear.It worked completely. I left Switch.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `switch (position)` use some other unique value in place of **position** to check the click event. So it'll be easy to check which list item you have clicked.